# Numpy ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence reading in list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this code that reads numbers and is meant to calculate std and %rms using numpy

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

values = []
line_number = 6

road = '/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl'
for pbpfile in glob.glob(os.path.join(road, 'pbpfile*')): 
    lines = open(pbpfile, 'r').readlines()
    while line_number < len(lines) :
        variables = lines[line_number].split()
        values.append(variables)
        line_number = line_number + 3

a = np.asarray(values).astype(np.float)
std = np.std(a)
rms = std * 100
print rms
```

However I keep getting the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "rmscalc.py", line 17, in <module>
a = np.asarray(values).astype(np.float)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Any idea how to fix this? I am new to python/numpy. If I print my values it looks something like this:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[2,4,5,6],[1,3,5,6]]
```

Comment: nope @bernie didn't work

Comment: Look at the pieces of the expression to see what exactly is giving the problem.  Look at (print) `values`.  Try `a=np.array(values)`. If it works print it.  Check its `dtype`.

Comment: I am able to print values. When doing a=np.array(values) - nothing new happens. the dtype is numpy.ndarray

Comment: I think the problem might be that each line of data is it's own "array" inside the list...is there a way to do this differently?

Comment: Just to test something out, could you try using tuples for your sub-sequences?  Like: `values.append(tuple(variables))`

Comment: `dtype` is never `ndarray!.  `type` yes, but not `dtype`.  I expect `dtype` is `object`, `float` or some sort of string.

Comment: Did you try `a = np.array(values, dtype='float64')`? If your array is all numeric -- like in your question -- I don't see why `numpy` cannot convert a simple `list` of lists to a 2D Array.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a modification to your code which can potentially fix your problem:

Initialize values as a numpy array, and use numpy append or concatenate:

```
values = np.array([], dtype=float)
```

Then inside loop:

```
values = np.append(values, [variables], axis=0)
# or
variables = np.array(lines[line_number].split(), dtype=float)
values = np.concatenate((values, variables), axis=0)
```

---

---

Alternatively, if you files are .csv (or any other type [Pandas can read](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/io.html)):

```
import pandas as pd
# Replace `read_csv` with your appropriate file reader

a = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(pbpfile)
               for pbpfile in glob.glob(os.path.join(road, 'pbpfile*'))]).values
# or
a = np.concatenate([pd.read_csv(pbpfile).values
                    for pbpfile in glob.glob(os.path.join(road, 'pbpfile*'))], axis=0)
```